# Pandas: how to groupby based on series pattern

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Having the following df:

```
pd.DataFrame({'bool':[True,True,True, False,True,True,True],
              'foo':[1,3,2,6,2,4,7]})
```

which results into:

```
    bool    foo
0   True    1
1   True    3
2   True    2
3   False   6
4   True    2
5   True    4
6   True    7
```

how to `groupby` Trues into 2 groups, to have indexes `[0:2]` in `group 1`, and `[4:6]` in `group 2` ?

The desired output:
group1:

```
    bool    foo
0   True    1
1   True    3
2   True    2
```

group2:

```
4   True    2
5   True    4
6   True    7
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you also post the desired output?

Comment: @anky_91, I have posted the desired output, as you have asked, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do :

```py
import numpy as np
x = df[df["bool"]].index.values
groups = np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x)>1)[0]+1)
df_groups = [df.iloc[gr, :] for gr in groups]
```

The output looks like :

```py
df_groups[0]
Out[56]: 
   bool  foo
0  True    1
1  True    3
2  True    2

df_groups[1]
Out[57]: 
   bool  foo
4  True    2
5  True    4
6  True    7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it :

```
# Split the dataframe by `Series` using `cumsum`
g =(~data['bool']).cumsum().where(data['bool'])

dfs= {'group_'+str(i+1):v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(data[['foo']].groupby(g))}
```

you can get access to each dataframe using the keys `'group_'+str(i+1)` like  `group_1`, `group_2`, ..etc:

```
print(dfs['group_1'])

   foo
0    1
1    3
2    2
```