# pandas list of dataframes to group by

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Having a list of pandas dataframes, how to concat them together into a single groupby object to have  vectorized calculations on them?

The dfs are similar and there is no chance to groupby them after concatination.

group n:

```
index some_values
0     2
1     3
2     2
3     2
```

group n+1:

```
index some_values
6     1
7     4
8     4
```

I could loop though the list to add an identifier, but due to the fact, that this operation is a part of an other loop, I have to avoid this inner loop.

To ask the question in the other way: how to add identifier with cumsum to rows of DFs in list, avoiding loop operation?

The story of how I actually got there:

First I had a DF of booleans to split on `Trues` and group `Falses`:

`initial_df`:

```
index boolean
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     True
4     True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
```

I used this sniped to get `groupes` of `dfs` I needed:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132096/pandas-how-to-groupby-based-on-series-pattern`

```
x = listing_calendar[~listing_calendar["available"]].index.values
groups = np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x)>1)[0]+1)
grouped_dfs = [listing_calendar.iloc[gr, :] for gr in groups]
```

`grouped_dfs[0]`:

```
    index boolean
    0     False
    1     False
    2     False
```

`grouped_dfs[2]`:

```
    index boolean
     5     False
     6     False
     7     False
     8     False
     9     False
```

the expected df to further `groupby`:

```
index boolean group_id
0     False     0  
1     False     0   
2     False     0
3     True      
4     True
5     False     1
6     False     1
7     False     1
8     False     1
9     False     1
```

or a `groupby` object insted of `grouped_dfs` to work with

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
s=np.where(~df.boolean,df.boolean.ne(df.boolean.shift()).cumsum(),np.nan)
final=df.assign(group=pd.Series(pd.factorize(s)[0]+1).replace(0,np.nan))
```

---

```
   index  boolean  group
0      0    False    1.0
1      1    False    1.0
2      2    False    1.0
3      3     True    NaN
4      4     True    NaN
5      5    False    2.0
6      6    False    2.0
7      7    False    2.0
8      8    False    2.0
9      9    False    2.0
```

***Details:***

Use [`np.where()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+where&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+where&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59j0l3.1456j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) using invert `~` and assign values with a comparision on the shifted values on the same series using `df.boolean.ne(df.boolean.shift()).cumsum()`:

```
np.where(~df.boolean,df.boolean.ne(df.boolean.shift()).cumsum(),np.nan)
#array([ 1.,  1.,  1., nan, nan,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.])
```

Then use [`factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) which returns -1 for `NaN`. As we are doing a +1 after that we then replace 0 with `np.nan`.

Comment: Note: to exactly match the OP's output use `final=df.assign(group=pd.Series(pd.factorize(s)[0]).replace(-1,np.nan))`

Comment: for some reason, I get 'group' full of NaNs

Comment: that was an issue with index, which is now reset_index. It works amazingly well, Thank you!

Comment: @DmitriyGrankin aha.. thanks for letting me know. :)